# Compare two files and write to a new file but only output a few lines?

Tags: python, file

I want to compare two txt files with all lines,but when i run the code it response only a few results,the loop is not effective run，It seems missed a lot of lines in File1,only appeared the first line of File1.

question:

my loop has any problem？Thanks very much！

```
def compareLines(filename1,filename2):

    File1=open(filename1,'r')
    File2=open(filename2,'r')
    File3=open("Result.txt",'w')

    finalList=[]
    for line1 in File1:
        for line2 in File2:
            set1=set(line1.split(" "))
            set2=set(line2.split(" "))
            print line1
            print line2
            similarNumber=len(set1.intersection(set2))/float(len(set1.union(set2)))
            File3.write('Simmilar rate:'+str(similarNumber)+' '+str(len(set1.intersection(set2)))+" words in incoindence\n")
            finalList.append(similarNumber)

    File1.close()
    File2.close()
    File3.close()

    os.remove(filename1)
    os.remove(filename2)

    return finalList
```

Comment: You're comparing the first line of file1 to every line of file2 at which point file2 is exhausted so nothing else happens. What exactly are you trying to do?>

Comment: It would still be inefficient, but you can reset `File2`'s pointer to the start so you can iterate over its lines again in the inner loop by doing `File2.seek(0)` right before `for line2 in File2:...`

Comment: If the files aren't large, you can load them both once, and then iterate through the list of lines to do the comparison.

Comment: Thanks every professor！I've solved the problem follow Nisan.H's said.

Answer (score 2):

You should re-open `File2` in inner loop or use `file.seek` to jump to the start of the file because after the first iteration the file pointer is at the end of `File2`.

Help on `file.seek`:

```
>>> print file.seek.__doc__
seek(offset[, whence]) -> None.  Move to new file position.

Argument offset is a byte count.  Optional argument whence defaults to
0 (offset from start of file, offset should be >= 0); other values are 1
(move relative to current position, positive or negative), and 2 (move
relative to end of file, usually negative,....
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answers above.And with my special appreciation to Nisan.H and Ashwini Chaudhary，I've solved the problem by your help,add only a line before "for line2 in File2"~~~

def compareLines(filename1,filename2):

```
File1=open(filename1,'r')
File2=open(filename2,'r')
File3=open("Result.txt",'w')

finalList=[]

for line1 in File1:
    File2.seek(0)
    for line2 in File2:
        set1=set(line1.split(" "))
        set2=set(line2.split(" "))
        print line1
        print line2
        similarNumber=len(set1.intersection(set2))/float(len(set1.union(set2)))
        File3.write('Simmilar rate:'+str(similarNumber)+' '+str(len(set1.intersection(set2)))+" words in incoindence\n")
        finalList.append(similarNumber)

File1.close()
File2.close()
File3.close()

os.remove(filename1)
os.remove(filename2)

return finalList
```