# how to break out of only one nested loop

Tags: python, loops, nested, break

I have two tab-delimited files, and I need to test every row in the first file against all the rows in the other file. For instance,

file1:

```
row1    c1    36    345   A
row2    c3    36    9949  B
row3    c4    36    858   C
```

file2:

```
row1    c1    3455  3800
row2    c3    6784  7843
row3    c3    10564 99302
row4    c5    1405  1563
```

let's say I would like to output all the rows in (file1) for which col[3] of file1 is smaller than any (not every) col[2] of file2, given that col[1] are the same.

Expected output:

```
row1    c1    36    345   A
row2    c3    36    9949  B
```

Since I am working in Ubuntu, I would like the input command to look like this:
`python code.py [file1] [file2] > [output]`

I wrote the following code:

```
import sys

filename1 = sys.argv[1]
filename2 = sys.argv[2]

file1 = open(filename1, 'r')
file2 = open(filename2, 'r')

done = False

for x in file1.readlines():
    col = x.strip().split()
    for y in file2.readlines():
        col2 = y.strip().split()
        if col[1] == col2[1] and col[3] < col2[2]:
            done = True
            break
        else: continue
print x
```

However, the output looks like this:

```
row2    c3    36    9949  B
```

This is evident for larger datasets, but basically I always get only the last row for which the condition in the nested loop was true. I am suspecting that "break" is breaking me out of both loops. I would like to know (1) how to break out of only one of the for loops, and (2) if this is the only problem I've got here.

Comment: `break` only breaks you out of the innermost loop.

Comment: Related: [Compare two files and write to a new file but only output a few lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514979/compare-two-files-and-write-to-a-new-file-but-only-output-a-few-lines)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`break` and `continue` apply to the innermost loop.

The issue is that you open the second file only once, and therefore it's only read once. When you execute `for y in file2.readlines():` for the second time, `file2.readlines()` returns an empty iterable.

Either move `file2 = open(filename2, 'r')` into the outer loop, or use `seek()` to rewind to the beginning of `file2`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to parse the numeric strings to their corresponding integer values.

You can use `int('hoge')` as follows.

```
import sys

filename1 = sys.argv[1]
filename2 = sys.argv[2]

with open(filename1) as file1:
    for x in file1:
        with open(filename2) as file2:
            col = x.strip().split()
            for y in file2:
                col2 = y.strip().split()
                if col[1] == col2[1] and int(col[3]) < int(col2[2]):
                    print x
```